# How to create a job that uses Powershell script?

Tags: sql-server-2014, sql-server-agent, powershell, scripting

I have a powershell script which deletes old backups from NAS storage. I have already tested it using Windows Powershell and it works but I couldn't perform the same thing in SQL Server. I have created a cmdExec type job and then wrote the script below (script is on desktop):

```
"C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"

"C:\Users\domainAccount\Desktop\"

".\deleteold.ps1 -FolderPath \\192.168.x.x\Backups -FileAge 2 -ListOnly -LogFile \\192.168.x.x\Backups\log.log"
```

But I do not get any result as when I run the job it just keeps running infinitely until I stop that job.

Comment: Not sure how the 3 lines in your question are being used. A one-liner should work as long as the execution account has access to the referenced script and UNC paths: `powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File "C:\Users\domainAccount\Desktop\\deleteold.ps1" -FolderPath "\\192.168.x.x\Backups" -FileAge 2 -ListOnly -LogFile "\\192.168.x.x\Backups\log.log"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the powershell file in as an argument

```
powershell.exe -file C:\Users\domainAccount\Desktop\deleteold.ps1 -FolderPath \\192.168.x.x\Backups -FileAge 2 -ListOnly -LogFile \\192.168.x.x\Backups\log.log
```

Or if the step type doesn’t have to be CmdExe you can change the type to PowerShell

Comment: I would avoid using the built-in PowerShell step type.  It doesn't use the latest version of PowerShell and I've found it to be far more trouble than it's worth.  Just save it as a ps1 file and then invoke powershell.exe directly through a cmdexec step.